# Overloading operators: operand order when using C++ literals

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, literals, operand

I am writing a class and I got to the point where I can do operations that mix my class type objects and C++ literals, but in one direction only.

here is a simplified code that shows the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class CLS
{
    string str;

public:
    CLS(const char* param)
    {    str = param;   }

    CLS operator+(const CLS& rhs)
    {
        str = str + rhs.str;
        return *this; }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CLS& rhs);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const CLS& rhs)
{
    out << rhs.str;
    return out; }

int main()
{
    CLS a("\n Hello ");
    CLS b("bye!\n\n");

    cout << a + "World!\n\n";

    //cout << "\n Good " + b; /* this is not possible because of the operands order */
}
```

As you see, I can do something like:

```
a + "W";
```

but not,

```
"W" + a;
```

As indicated in the last line of the code.

I understand the reason.

The first is equivalent to:

```
a.operator+("W");
```

which is covered by my class. However, the second is like,

```
"W".operator(a);
```

which is not covered and the literal itself is not an object of a class as I understand. And so, the expression as whole cannot be.

I understand I can create a user defined literals, but this is not what I want to do here. (although I am not sure if they gonna work or not).

I could not find any hint browsing questions I supposed to be related on this site, and I could not get something related to my issue on the net.

My question:

**Is there a way that can make either order works?**

Comment: Binary operators like `+` should generally be free functions, not members, in which case the problem goes away, as suitable conversions can be performed on both the left and right hand operands..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
cout << "\n Good " + b; /* this is not possible because of the operands order */
```

does not work because you made `operator+` member (and not const member). If you rewrite it as standalone function (probably friend) then this problem would go away:

```
friend 
CLS operator+(const CLS& lhs, const CLS& rhs)
{
    CLS r;
    r.str = lhs.str + rhs.str;
    return r; 
}
```

if you create additional ctor that accepts `const std::string &` it would be even simpler:

```
friend 
CLS operator+(const CLS& lhs, const CLS& rhs)
{
    return CLS( lhs.str + rhs.str );
}
```

note, you should rewrite existing constructor this way:

```
CLS(const char* param) : str( param )
{}
```

it is cleaner and more efficient way

Answer (score 2):

You can add a global function:

```
inline CLS operator+(const char *lhs, const CLS& rhs)
{
    return CLS(lhs) + rhs;
}
```

Comment: `CLS operator+(const CLS &lhs, const CLS& rhs)` is enough as there is not explicit constructor that accepts `const char *`